# MikTeX installation error, "The member could not bex extracted from the cabinet file"

Tags: miktex, installing

MiKTeX Setup 2.9.5870 Report

```
Date: Monday, May 09, 2016
Time: 10:28:25
OS version: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit, Service Pack 3, build 7600
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: false
SharedSetup: false
Setup path: C:\Users\Ajas\Downloads\LATEX\basic-miktex-2.9.5872-x64.exe
UserRoots: <none specified>
UserData: <none specified>
UserConfig: <none specified>
CommonRoots: <none specified>
CommonData: <none specified>
CommonConfig: <none specified>

Installation: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
initializing setup service...
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX"
package repository: C:\Users\Ajas\AppData\Local\Temp\mik5822
visiting repository C:\Users\Ajas\AppData\Local\Temp\mik5822...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: fb1e8366e42a4bfee55fb5a2476c9e77
going to install 10207 file(s) (169 package(s))
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-spanish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cyrillic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.cab...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.cab...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo-font.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-base.cab...

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Extractor\CabExtractor.cpp
  source line: 368
  message: The member could not bex extracted from the cabinet file.
  info: cabinetPath="C:\Users\Ajas\AppData\Local\Temp\mik5822\miktex-bibtex-base.cab", 
    ret="2", member="texmf\doc\bibtex\btxbst.doc"
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is your question, exactly? Please advise. Are you asking why the installation process terminated rather early, with an error message to boot?

Comment: Sound as if the cab is faulty. You could try another repository. (But it is possible that will have to wait as the miktex servers will be down shortly: http://www.miktex.org/ )